# Push Empty Directories with ADB

Tags: adb

**What do I want?**

I want to push some directories from my desktop to my android phone. The directories are empty, but the folder name contains important meta-data. The structure is not changeable.

**What is the Issue?**

If I try to push via adb, I get the following warning:

```
adb: warning: skipping empty directory
```

**What have I tried?**

As a workaround I could use the MTP protocol. But this protocol is not stable and crashes a lot, especially if you want to copy multiple files. I can't get it work on linux anyways, so adb seems to be the best choice.

**My Questions**

1. What is the reasoning to skip empty directories? It seems like an arbitrary (and annoying) design choice for me.
2. Is there a flag to NOT skip empty directories?
3. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to get around this limitation of adb in the [adb source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/aosp/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/file_sync_client.cpp#855).  The sad part is that there is already a bug ticket mentioned to change this behavior (the comment was added Nov 2015).

For pushing empty directories I would try to build a TAR archive (e.g. `my.tar`), and execute tar extraction on-device via `adb shell` providing the TAR archive via stdin:

```
adb shell tar xv -C /storage/emulated/0 < my.tar
```

If the tar files contains empty directories they will be correctly extracted on device.